# Should we police the Martian questions for "movie" tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

There seems to be a glut of new questions prompted by the release of the movie "Martian".

If this film (haven't seen yet) is as different from the book it's based on as the usual pattern is, we should probably police film-specific questions and tag them with [movie](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movie) or [book-vs-film](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-vs-film) as appropriate.

Should we?

Comment: Related:http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/104779/how-faithful-is-the-film-the-martian-to-the-book

Comment: I'm looking forward to having a gold tag for "movie". Pretty much the most useless gold tag ever.

Comment: @Valorum - nope, that'd be "Discussion" gold tag in Meta, i venture.

Comment: @DVK-in-exile - That one's a positive menace. I'm scared to vote *anything* as a dupe for fear of spawning yet another "***WTF did Valorum do now?***" meta-discussion

Comment: @Valorum - when I dupehammer, I tend to leave a very nice comment explaining that I did so, and if the OP strongly disagrees, to leave a comment explaining why I'm wrong. So far, i don't think i had a single instance of drama originating from dupehammered OPs that I recall. Whether it's because of my form, or because of my reluctance to close when i'm not ironclad 100% sure, is unknown.

Comment: @DVK-in-exile - I suspect it's because I use the dupehammer quite a lot. I could just as easily let things slide, wait for a few users to pile on and avoid the drama but why the hell should I? If it's a dupe, it's a dupe. That's why I've got the badge in the first place. If I'm supposed to feel ashamed of using it, then they shouldn't give them out.

Comment: @Valorum - the fact that disagreed with at least a couple of your dupehammers means that you may be erring on the side of not-quite-always-correctness. (not because it's me or because i'm always right, but because disagreement exists at all).

Comment: @DVK-in-exile - Despite my brash attitude, I have never openly claimed to be infallible. Obviously I think it, but I don't say it out loud.

Comment: @DVK-in-exile - Cue extensive meta discussion "***Valorum said in a comment that he thinks he's infallible, quite how offended should I be on a scale of 1 (very) to 10 (very very)?***"

Comment: @Valorum - admitting to fallability tends to help avoid drama, in my experience. People tend to get aggravated by arrogance, **even if arrogance is warranted**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The movie isn't particularly different from the book. It's obviously a shortened version of the tale. However, a couple events are changed from the book, but I think that's minor enough that we don't need special tagging. The content of questions will likely make it clear which version the question is about.

Comment: I would take this over my answer, until we get enough questions, if ever.

Comment: Thanks, seems sensible. I'll provisionally accept unless someone comes up with more persuasive arguments to do something else.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's beneficial to use the Metatag [movie](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movie). I'd be more in favour  of using [martian-movie](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/martian-movie)

Comment: Definitely martian-movie.

Comment: Might `martian-movie` not confuse people with movies made by Martians?

Comment: @Xantec http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MostWritersAreHuman

Comment: Damn! I just lost 24 minutes on TvTropes...

Comment: @beppe9000 - you got off easy. Here's a [willpower] badge for you.